# Multiple Custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to create a tableview with cells that display text and photos and just text. I've created 2 custom tableviewcells but I am only able to get one of them to show up at a time when I want them to be mixed in the tableview. Basically, if the post has no image, I want it to load the TextFeedCell, if it does, I want it to load the photoFeedCell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if FeedTVCellWithPhoto().post?.imageContentName != "" {
                let photoFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(FeedTVController().cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedTVCellWithPhoto
                photoFeedCell.post = posts[indexPath.section]
                return photoFeedCell
            }
            else {
                let textFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(FeedTVController().textCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedTVCellText
                textFeedCell.post = posts[indexPath.section]
                return textFeedCell
            }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1:**

**Both are registered:**

```
 tableView?.registerClass(FeedTVCellWithPhoto.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
 tableView?.registerClass(FeedTVCellText.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: textCellId)
```

Both of these custom cells work on their own, when I implement them without the conditional statement. The problem comes when I implement them with the conditional(as-is above), I get the posts that don't have images but still get empty imageViews inserted into them.

FeedTVCellWithPhoto

```
class FeedTVCellWithPhoto: UITableViewCell {

    var post:Post? {
        didSet {
            if let name = post?.name {

                let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)])

                attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\nMay 23  •  Los Angeles, CA  •  ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGrayColor()]))

                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5

                attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.string.characters.count))

                let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                attachment.image = UIImage(named: "globe")
                attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -2, 12, 12)
                attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))

                nameLabel.attributedText = attributedText
            }
            if let textContent = post?.textContent {
                postTextView.text = textContent
            }
            if let profileImageName = post?.profileImageName {
                profileImg.image = UIImage(named: profileImageName)
            }
            if let imageContent = post?.imageContentName {
                print(imageContent)
                postImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageContent)
            }
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: FeedTVController().cellId)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let nameLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let profileImg:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile")
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let postTextView:UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "This is text from a post!"
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        textView.scrollEnabled = false
        textView.editable = false
        return textView
    }()

    let postImageView:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return imageView

    }()

    let likesCommentsLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "25 Likes       10.7K Comments"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
        label.textColor = UIColor.rgb(155, green: 161, blue: 171)
        return label
    }()

    let dividerLineView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(226, green: 228, blue: 232)
        return view
    }()

    let likeButton = FeedTVCellWithPhoto.buttonForTitle("Like", imageName: "like")
    let commentButton = FeedTVCellWithPhoto.buttonForTitle("Comment", imageName: "comment")
    let shareButton = FeedTVCellWithPhoto.buttonForTitle("Share", imageName: "share")

    static func buttonForTitle(title:String, imageName:String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(143, green: 150, blue: 163), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blueColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
        button.setTitleColor(.redColor() , forState: .Selected)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named:imageName), forState: .Normal)
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 0)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        return button
    }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(profileImg)
        addSubview(postTextView)
        addSubview(postImageView)
        addSubview(likesCommentsLabel)
        addSubview(dividerLineView)
        addSubview(likeButton)
        addSubview(commentButton)
        addSubview(shareButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-8-[v0(44)]-8-[v1]|", views: profileImg, nameLabel)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0]", views: nameLabel)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: postTextView)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]-12-|", views: dividerLineView)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]|", views: likesCommentsLabel)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0(v2)][v1(v2)][v2]|", views: likeButton, commentButton, shareButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(44)]|", views: commentButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(44)]|", views: shareButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0(44)]-4-[v1]-4-[v2(200)][v3(44)][v4(1)][v5(44)]|", views: profileImg, postTextView, postImageView, likesCommentsLabel, dividerLineView, likeButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: postImageView)


    }
}
```

FeedTVCellText

```
class FeedTVCellText: UITableViewCell {
    var post:Post? {
        didSet {
            if let name = post?.name {

                let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)])

                attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\nMay 23  •  Los Angeles, CA  •  ", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGrayColor()]))

                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5

                attributedText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.string.characters.count))

                let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                attachment.image = UIImage(named: "globe")
                attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -2, 12, 12)
                attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))

                nameLabel.attributedText = attributedText
            }
            if let textContent = post?.textContent {
                postTextView.text = textContent
            }
            if let profileImageName = post?.profileImageName {
                profileImg.image = UIImage(named: profileImageName)
            }

        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: FeedTVController().textCellId)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let nameLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        return label
    }()

    let profileImg:UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profile")
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let postTextView:UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "This is text from a post!"
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)
        textView.scrollEnabled = false
        textView.editable = false
        return textView
    }()

    let likesCommentsLabel:UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "25 Likes       10.7K Comments"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
        label.textColor = UIColor.rgb(155, green: 161, blue: 171)
        return label
    }()

    let dividerLineView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(226, green: 228, blue: 232)
        return view
    }()

    let likeButton = FeedTVCellText.buttonForTitle("Like", imageName: "like")
    let commentButton = FeedTVCellText.buttonForTitle("Comment", imageName: "comment")
    let shareButton = FeedTVCellText.buttonForTitle("Share", imageName: "share")

    static func buttonForTitle(title:String, imageName:String) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(143, green: 150, blue: 163), forState: .Normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blueColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
        button.setTitleColor(.redColor() , forState: .Selected)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named:imageName), forState: .Normal)
        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 0)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
        return button
    }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(profileImg)
        addSubview(postTextView)
        addSubview(likesCommentsLabel)
        addSubview(dividerLineView)
        addSubview(likeButton)
        addSubview(commentButton)
        addSubview(shareButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-8-[v0(44)]-8-[v1]|", views: profileImg, nameLabel)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0]", views: nameLabel)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-4-[v0]-4-|", views: postTextView)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]-12-|", views: dividerLineView)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]|", views: likesCommentsLabel)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0(v2)][v1(v2)][v2]|", views: likeButton, commentButton, shareButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(44)]|", views: commentButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(44)]|", views: shareButton)
        addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0(44)]-4-[v1]-4-[v2(44)][v3(1)][v4(44)]|", views: profileImg, postTextView, likesCommentsLabel, dividerLineView, likeButton)


    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

Post model

```
class Post {
    var name:String?
    var profileImageName:String?
    var textContent:String?
    var imageContentName:String?
}
```

Comment: This is entirely fine in iOS so either you have entered incorrect cell identifiers or section / row counts or there is a logic error in your code. I recommend you check the cell identifiers in the storyboard and `FeedTVController()` then use the debugger to step through your code to check the logic.

Comment: The code looks fine. Double check the contents of your variables incl. `post`. Check the identifiers in Interface Builder/storyboard.

Comment: If you are using .xib files then you need to register them to your tableview.

Comment: I'll add my code for each cell to the post. I know they both work individually because when I remove the if-else statement and just swap each of them in, they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking against and actual post. You are creating an instance of a cell that doesn't actually have a post value.

So you can maybe the following? And possibly reload the tableview once the content is parsed.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var post : Post? = posts[indexPath.section]

    if let _ = post?.imageContentName {
        let photoFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(FeedTVController().cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedTVCellWithPhoto
        photoFeedCell.post = post?
        return photoFeedCell
    } 

    let textFeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(FeedTVController().textCellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedTVCellText
    textFeedCell.post = post?
    return textFeedCell
}
```

Comment: I added your code but I am still getting the cell with photo for all of them (even if there isn't a photo). It's still adding the imageView even though its not in that cell

Comment: @MichaelWilliams I updated my answer, it appears you are just creating an instance of a cell, that doesn't have an actual post value. Give that a try :)

Comment: still getting the same problem. the photoFeedCell is being returned for every post

Comment: @MichaelWilliamsI forgot to add the nil check on imageContentName. Can you put a breakpoint at the if statement, and do a `po post` and a `po post?.imageContentName` the console?

Comment: I have the nil check in their with mine. I get "Some : <Post: 0x7fdaab56b640>" from the console

Comment: @MichaelWilliams what about `po post?.imageContentName` ?

Comment: i get "Some: "coffee""

Comment: as it iterates through each post, i don't get a nil until the 3rd post which is intended but it still returns photoFeedCell

Comment: @MichaelWilliams I just updated the code with a && statement, try that one out

Comment: @MichaelWilliams what do FeedTVController().cellId and FeedTVController().textCellId return?

Comment: The imageContentName is explicitly set to nil for those posts. Will adding the isEmpty do anything since nothing will be empty? It will have nil if it has no image.

Comment: @MichaelWilliamsdid you mean to user indexPath.section ? or indexPath.row?

Comment: they return "PhotoCell" and "TextCell" respectively. I did mean to use indexPath.section. Each post is a new section.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams can you try optionally unwrapping the imageContentName?

Comment: @MichaelWilliams one last thing I guess we can look at. Can you post the code for he Post model class?

Comment: posted it as Update 2

Comment: @MichaelWilliams can you also post the numberOfSections method, and the numberOfrows in section?

Comment: numberOfSections is "return posts.count and" and numberOf Rows is "return 1"

Comment: @MichaelWilliams I updated the code to one last approach. Do you reload the table view once you parse the content?

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much for working with me for this long on this.

Comment: @MichaelWilliams anytime man, had me stumped there for a moment. StackExchange should have a debugging screen share feature, could of been useful